# Delete request without id parameter in .net webApi

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have .net core WebApi like below. And it is working perfectly. But, when I write `[HttpDelete]` instead of `[HttpDelete("{id}")]` , then it doesn't work. What can be reason ?

My url : http://localhost:5004/api/Student/DeleteStudent/23

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    //[HttpDelete] ///////////////// This is not working
    [HttpDelete("{id}")] /////////// This is working
    public async Task<ServiceResult> DeleteStudent(int id)
    {
      return await studentService.DeleteStudent(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: How will MVC know where to get the ID from? Why do you want to remove the routing template?

Comment: I'm sending only one parameter. I thought, it can know @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Forexample in this site ; https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/httpdelete-method-in-asp-net-web-api-part/  @PanagiotisKanavos He didn't use id parameter.

Comment: without the id  route template parameter, that only other way to populate the value would be via query string (ie `http://localhost:5004/api/Student/DeleteStudent?id=23`). Either way, the id needs to be provided to know which record to delete

Comment: Thanks @ Nkosi. I think, this is what I'm looking for. It worked. Can you write as answer and I will mark as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the `{id}` route template parameter, the only other way to populate the value would be via query string

```
http://localhost:5004/api/Student/DeleteStudent?id=23
```

The route table will match the querystring parameter to the action parameter to make the match.

Either way, the `id` needs to be provided to know which action to call and which record to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the router about your api signature.. now by replacing `[HttpDelete("{id}")]` by `[HttpDelete]` your signature become `api/[controller]/[action]`, thus your router will ignore anything after that signature.

You can define custom route if you like to leave it as `[HttpDelete]` where you will also specify id as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @MichelHanna. Nkosi's answer solved my issue.